# getting nullpointer exception when filtering listview

Tags: android, listview, filter

Getting this exception in lohcat when trying to search into my edittext box.
when i am entering any latter in search box suddnly my application getting forced close and displays this exception.

```
03-06 10:38:31.433: E/AndroidRuntime(750): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-06 10:38:31.433: E/AndroidRuntime(750): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-06 10:38:31.433: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getCount(SimpleAdapter.java:93)
03-06 10:38:31.433: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.widget.AdapterView.checkFocus(AdapterView.java:700)
03-06 10:38:31.433: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onInvalidated(AdapterView.java:823)
03-06 10:38:31.433: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.widget.AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onInvalidated(AbsListView.java:5600)
03-06 10:38:31.433: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyInvalidated(DataSetObservable.java:47)
03-06 10:38:31.433: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated(BaseAdapter.java:59)
03-06 10:38:31.433: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.widget.SimpleAdapter$SimpleFilter.publishResults(SimpleAdapter.java:383)
03-06 10:38:31.433: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:282)
03-06 10:38:31.433: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-06 10:38:31.433: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-06 10:38:31.433: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
03-06 10:38:31.433: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-06 10:38:31.433: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-06 10:38:31.433: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-06 10:38:31.433: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-06 10:38:31.433: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: a fine example for [filtering listview](http://rakhi577.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/buttons-on-list-view-with-easy-searching-in-android/)

Comment: Please post some code where you are getting exception